# How to remove extra zeros in my text file?

Tags: c, text-files

When I try to produce a text file using my program, I always get a bunch of extra zeros and then the input that I typed in. However, I don't want those extra zeros and just want my input.

My file would look something like this:

0.000000

0.000000

Then the input I want.

Here is the function that is in my larger part of code:

```
void saveEmployee(int totalEmployees)
{
    FILE *employeeFile;
    char fileName[40];
    int counter = 0;

    printf("Save file (add .txt at the end): ");
    scanf_s("%s", fileName, 40);
    fopen_s(&employeeFile, fileName, "w");
    for (counter = 0; counter < totalEmployees; counter++)
        {
            fprintf(employeeFile, "%s\n", employeeList[counter].name);
            fprintf(employeeFile, "%lf\n", employeeList[counter].worked);
            fprintf(employeeFile, "%lf\n", employeeList[counter].rate);
            fprintf(employeeFile, "%lf\n", employeeList[counter].gross);
            fprintf(employeeFile, "%lf\n", employeeList[counter].base);
            fprintf(employeeFile, "%lf\n", employeeList[counter].overtime);
            fprintf(employeeFile, "%lf\n", employeeList[counter].taxes);
            fprintf(employeeFile, "%lf\n", employeeList[counter].net);
        }

    fclose(employeeFile);
}
```

I believe that this is the function that is causing me issues, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour. Notes: Do not parenthesise `data` (less readable, nonsense). Format your code properly; currently it is just unreadable (and too long, btw) - use `edit` to edit and see the help. Read about `select` statement. `int menu()` is no valid declaration for a function since C99. Use `int menu(void)`. C isn **not** C++!

Answer (score 2):

Look up the specification of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) and learn how to control the format.  For example, you might use:

```
fprintf(employeeFile, "%.2f\n", employeeList[counter].worked);
```

to print the hours worked with 2 decimal places.  (And yes, I dropped the `l`, and no it didn't matter in the original, but it also doesn't matter that it isn't in the replacement, and after reading the specification, you'll know why.)